# Should a unit test assert what a function doesn't do?

Tags: unit-testing

Sometimes I see bits of code in functions that I suspect could be changed in a specific way later that would break its functionality. For example, function A could be changed to call function B, but it shouldn't.

Should there be a unit test that asserts that function A does not call function B?

---

The case I am thinking of is a UI component in a web application that calls an API using ajax requests, via a layer. In a certain case it should call one function in this layer, and in another case, a different function.

The consequence of calling the wrong one, in the real world, is that it fails asynchronously. It's just that it'll use a bit of bandwidth, server time, and make it difficult to debug issues as it certainly looks like something is wrong when inspecting network behavior. As long as the correct one is called at some point, the widget works as expected.

Comment: Please give an example use case

Comment: @CandiedOrange Done!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, unit tests should verify *behavior*, not implementation details. So you verify some input to A give the expected output. If someone rewrites the function A to call B, but it still yields the correct output - then it just shows that calling B is not a problem after all, since the function still works.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: it depends.

This question really only applies well when you have some sort of behavioral testing options in place. For example, when you use a mocking framework. When you run actual code it's really hard to test that something did *not* happen. You could rely on some nasty side-effects, but that just makes the test highly coupled and brittle.

Given proper isolation via mocks/stubs though, there certainly are situations, in which you want to verify the correct behavior (instead of the correct result). And in some cases, the correct behavior is explicitly defined by not doing something.

Should the test do that though? It really depends on the consequences should the unwanted behavior occur. Usually, if you have a good reason to dictate your code *not* to call something, you have that same good reason to test against it.

Here are a few examples highlighting cases in which you may want to do that and for what reasons:

Caches: You have some cache functionality, which can quickly return results instead of expensive computations. Testing that the code takes results from the cache and does *not* perform the computation makes a lot of sense.

Decorator pattern: The decorator pattern allows you to decorate a class and delegate all method calls to an original implementation, except in those places you want a changed behavior. You write the decorator because you want differing behavior and it's another reason, where your code's intention is already to *not* call the original method.

Filters: Sometimes you run through collections, filter out certain elements and perform an operation on them. Testing that the filtering is correct can be made via ensuring that the operation is *not* performed on the respective elements.

Answer (score 2):

In a Test-Driven Development context, unit tests should assert what is specified. If a requirement forbids usage of a specific function, this should appear in some unit test. Otherwise, either that test is not needed or specification needs to be amended.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that for example when making 2 ajax calls results in a negative performance.
But the real issue here is single responsibility:

```
function getVehicleName(type, id) {
  if(type === 'bike') {
    return getWithAjax('/bikes/' + id).name;
  }else{
    return getWithAjax('/cars/' + id).name;
  }
}
```

An alternative would be (very simple, can be optimized further, that if statement off course is not very beautiful but in this simple case it works):

```
function getVehicleName(type, id) {
  return getVehicle(type, id).name;
}

function getVehicle(type, id) {
  if(type === 'bike') {
    return getWithAjax('/bikes/' + id);
  }else{
    return getWithAjax('/cars/' + id);
  }
}
```

Can be usefull, even more separated:

```
function getVehicleName(vehicleObj) {
  return vehicleObj;
}

function getVehicle(type, id) {
  if(type === 'bike') {
    return getWithAjax('/bikes/' + id);
  }else{
    return getWithAjax('/cars/' + id);
  }
}

//call:
alert(getVehicleName(getVehicle('car', 1)));

// optional helper:
function loadVehicleAndGetName(type, id) {
  return getVehicleName(getVehicle('car', 1));
}

//call:
alert(loadVehicleAndGetName('car', 1));
```

The last one really has all responsibilities separated and allows you to easily test each of them. You can mock getWithAjax now very simple also.

So now it makes total sense to test that getVehicle call the right api. Calls only once the api. And that in the end solves your problem. You can now make the behavior of getVehicle so specific that it's very easy to also test the boundaries of what it should not do.

Is that testing internals? Not sure on that, I think is more about testing correct behavior: "I expect it to get that vehicle once" and since it's unit testing I think it fits there fine.